# Using AsyncTask inside Activity to perform multiple tasks

Tags: android

Consider this: I've got Activity, in onCreate() I start AsyncTask to load its content. I've followed [this sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/rotation/async/RotationAsync.java). Now my problem is: I want to download file in that Activity, using AsyncTask. But I don't know how to make existing AsyncTask do various tasks. 
If anyone had the same problem, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your actual issue?  Why can't you put you file-downloading code inside the async task you have?

Comment: What is the purpose of your AsyncTask? Why did you use that particular sample?

Comment: When Activity is lauched at first time, I need to load its content, from remote server. And then when user clicks on button, I need to load file from server. All that I need to do in separate thread and to be able to handle screen rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've succeeded to make it call again and again... you have to instantiate your class as a null first (int the Activity).

```
MyAsyncTask asyncTask = null;
```

and then put it in a try... catch block:

```
asyncTask = (MyAsyncTask) new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);
```

The other thing you're interrested about is the differenc methods you want to run... Well, I wanted to do the same, but I've had no time writing that one, but I've thought about it on the way home from work.

I think your class extending AsyncTask should look like this:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> { }
```

create some variables or ArrayLists in your AsyncTask, and do the decision on the overriden onPreExecute() method where you have to make a switch, or some if's. Do the call/work on the overriden doInBackground(), get the result, and process it in the overriden onPostExecute() method.

I don't know if this line works, since I've had no time to experiment it, I really just thought about it, how to... :)

But I hope the thought helps at least! :)

Answer (score 1):

You must implement two separate AsyncTasks with different doInBackground methods or add file downloading to existing one.

Remember that (from documentation):

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)